# QA a Chat Bot Relating to UX/CX

Tags: data, heuristics, chatbots, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I've been tasked with checking over a chat bot from a UX/CX perspective. This is the first time I've looked a chat bot from this point of view. What can I do a heuristic analysis and UX baseline metrics for?

Eg response time, CSAT, declare it's a bot, reduction in phone calls or emails

It's AI and ML capabilities are in the early learning stages so it’s still scripted conversation.

Comment: What is the issue with the chat bot? Here are some helpful articles https://uxdesign.cc/chatbots-conversational-ui/home

Comment: I don't know what the issues are yet - it's just been created and it's being QA'd by various people/teams. I'm trying to find UX/CX issues with it and was wondering what I should be looking for.

Comment: This is too broad a question, because you're asking for whole UX criteria for chat bots. If there's one single, specific issue you need to know the answer to then we can help with that, but general advice or listing out things to review in chatbots is just too broad to answer correctly. It's the sort of thing you'd get whole books written on.

Answer (score 2):

You might do a [Heuristic Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation) to discover basic UX issues. Nielsen's original is pretty general, so it should apply to chatbots.

Googling "heuristic evaluation chatbot" returns this article, which, at first glance, looks helpful: [Usability Heuristics for Bots](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/usability-heuristics-for-bots-7075132d2c92). It talks specifically about how to apply Nielsen's heuristics to bots.